# Losing last row after table execute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created very simple table in SQL Server.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Teams](
    [TeamID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Teams] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Teams_TeamID]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [TeamID]
```

I fill it with data, execute it and it loses last row. It doesn't depends how much row I enter, it always loses last one. It happens with all my tables and I can't understand why? Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you expand on your statement "I fill it with data, execute it ...", how are you filling it with data and what do you mean by "execute it"?

Comment: Thank you for all your attention. I'm working with SSMS in graphical regime. SQLMenace answer was helpful. I just needed to move cursor on next row. I will be more carefull next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this through the SSMS designer? if so move the cursor to the next row, this will ensure that the row you were on previous is inserted, otherwise SSMS will think you are still in edit mode